# How to get an element of array in state in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have array in `this.state.placeinfo`, and I want to show `id`.

```
0:{
  id: "2"
  latitude: "35.737939"
  longitude: "139.7400265"
}
```

I code like this, but the result says `undefined`.

```
console.log(this.state.placeinfo.id)

...
const line = this.state.placeinfo
console.log(line.id)
```

Do you have any idea to show `id`?

Comment: Does `console.log(this.state.placeinfo.id)` return anything?

Comment: It says `undefined`

Comment: You are saying it is an array. So, `this.state.placeinfo[0].id`

Comment: Is `this.state.placeinfo` an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.state.placeinfo` contains an array of Objects.  When you did

```
const line = this.state.placeinfo
```

`line` was actually an array, which doesn't have the ID property you are looking for. It's only when you get an element from within that array, will you have access to those properties.

So, if you wanted to get the ID of the first object, within the array it would be:

```
const line = this.state.placeinfo[0];
```

Then `console.log(line.id)` will work.